# Addressing Error in iretq

Tags: assembly, kernel, x86-64, interrupt-handling

I am trying to debug a custom kernel that is apparently making an error during an `iretq` instruction. I have the following data pushed on the stack, in this order, from most to least recent (all of the values below are 8 bytes in size), with the current location of the stack pointer as indicated:

```
trapno
trapfn
err
rip     <- %rsp
cs
rflags
rsp
```

When I execute the `iretq`, it is my understanding that it will pop the `rip`, `cs`, `rflags`, and `rsp` values from the stack, in that order, and place them into the corresponding registers. However, for whatever reason the CPU is skipping the `rip` field and starting with `cs` instead. This has the effect that `%rip` has the value intended for `%cs`, and `%rflags` has the value intended for `%rsp`. This is causing a crash, as `%cs` does not contain a valid instruction address.

Note that the fields located above `rip` in the above listing were part of a large structure that was allocated on the stack, and then deallocated by moving `%rsp` back past its start, to the `rip` field. I have tried adjusting the amount by which `%rsp` is moved, to no effect.

Comment: Hmm, if IRET pops rsp then it will also pop the ss register.  Since you don't seem to have one on the stack, a crash is guaranteed.

Comment: @HansPassant – There actually is an `ss` on the stack, right below `rsp`; I just didn’t list it as I didn’t think it would be relevant.

Comment: For some exceptions the CPU pushes an error code, and for other exceptions and all other interrupts (IRQs, etc) it doesn't. I'd guess that you've got assembly language stubs that assume CPU put an error code on the stack when it didn't,; causing one/some interrupts (but not others) to crash at the IRETQ.